# Magento 2 Order Attribute Creations

Tags: attributes, sales-order, magento-2.1.3

I want to create three new order attribute for checkout page, so I found good tutorials to create using install script but I want to add text boxes to checkout page and save it to database,

Are there any simple solution ? ( free module )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new checkout field, save a value in the database and display in the backend is very long process, there are lots of paid extension available for this but I would afraid suggest you look into below link, In this link, they are adding `date picker` you can replace with `textbox`. And step by step by guidance is worth to read.

https://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

> Note:: I am adding the link as answer because this answer is very long

Comment: thank you, I followed this but I'm using paid extension for onestep checkout, so difficult to add content there,  Do you know any way to save custom html field data to db here,

Comment: I think this is the easy solution, but if you are using some custom extension then postcode what you have done so far so someone can understand and answer your question. @ssk8323

Comment: Thanks all, it's issue with my 3rd party paid module, I requested the support, Here I have found good module https://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-2-order-comments-extension-for-checkout/  This will help up. thanks